# Bootstrap menu, center element between 2 elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following menu :

```css
.navbar {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
 background: #fff;
 border: 0;
 max-height: 73px
}

.navbar-center>span>a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

#header>.navbar>div:nth-child(2)>ul>li:nth-child(2)>a {
 padding-right: 0;
}

#header>.navbar>div:nth-child(2)>ul>li:nth-child(3)>a {
 padding-left: 0;
}

section#header {
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 80px;
}

#header>.navbar>.navbar-center {
 margin-top: -7px;
}

#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(2),
#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(3),
#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(4),
#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(5) {
 margin-left: 6%
}

.navbar-nav {
 float: none;
 margin: 0 0 0 11%
}

.navbar-brand {
 float: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-center {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(2),
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(3),
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(4),
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(5) {
  margin: 0
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
 .navbar-center {
  text-align: inherit;
  margin-left: 3%;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <a href="#">
            LOGO
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-center navbar-brand">
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 1</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 2</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 3</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 4</a></span>
            <a href="#">
                CENTER ME
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li style="background: #244b5a;">
                    <a href="/logout.php">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

I would like to center the block `CENTER ME` between the left and right element.

[image]

I tried using `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Fix your snippet

Comment: "Center me" has margin left because of #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 15%
}. I think you should change the approach to split your menu

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Snippet has been fixed

Comment: Have you take a look at bootstrap docs? You can use things like ```.navbar-left``` and ```.navbar-right``` for left and right into navbar and you can use ```.container``` and ```.centered-block``` to get your element into navbar centered.

Comment: @ElieMorin I'm already using `.navbar-right`

Comment: Unless I'm blind, your snippet and image do not match. Doesn't seem fixed to me :/

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy You should open as full page :)

Comment: @Executable yeah, but what about other classes I point to you. You need to put an element after  menu 4 that will take all the remaining width of the parent. Then, into that element, put another one display as block that have margin left and right auto.

Comment: @ElieMorin Could you please share a snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, the main goal is to do this :
You need to put an element after menu 4 that will take all the remaining width of the parent. Then, into that element, put another one display as block that have margin left and right auto.

I also said that bootstrap 3 come with helper classes that help you do this. You can find them by reading the docs there: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats

Be attentive to that part of the code:

```
        <div class="navbar-center navbar-brand">
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 1</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 2</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 3</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 4</a></span>
            <div class=container">
                <div class="center-block">center me</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The `.container` create the element that will fill in the remaining space.
`.center-block` will apply the following CSS and both of them come out of the box with bootstrap 3.

```
// Class
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**ATTENTION** The following snippet contains other css bug that prevent it to work as expected. You will need to expand the snippet to really see the behavior of the centered element.

```css
.navbar {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
 background: #fff;
 border: 0;
 max-height: 73px
}

.navbar-center>span>a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

#header>.navbar>div:nth-child(2)>ul>li:nth-child(2)>a {
 padding-right: 0;
}

#header>.navbar>div:nth-child(2)>ul>li:nth-child(3)>a {
 padding-left: 0;
}

section#header {
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 80px;
}

#header>.navbar>.navbar-center {
 margin-top: -7px;
}

#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(2),
#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(3),
#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(4),
#header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(5) {
 margin-left: 6%
}

.navbar-nav {
 float: none;
 margin: 0 0 0 11%
}

.navbar-brand {
 float: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-center {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(2),
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(3),
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(4),
 #header>.navbar>.navbar-center>span:nth-child(5) {
  margin: 0
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
 .navbar-center {
  text-align: inherit;
  margin-left: 3%;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <a href="#">
            LOGO
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-center navbar-brand">
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 1</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 2</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 3</a></span>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU 4</a></span>
            <div class=container-fluid">
                <div class="center-block">center me</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li style="background: #244b5a;">
                    <a href="/logout.php">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried the solution, but the container doesn't take the full width https://jsfiddle.net/zmsrypa2/

Comment: Yeah, a forgot that container have a max width. container-fluid does not.